# Why doesn't the queue data structure support random access

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue

After reading  [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I understand that a queue in C# has an internal array where the elements of the queue are stored in sequence, a start index and an end index. I don't understand why you shouldn't be able to read or write the nth element. All you'd have to do is `return array[(n + start) % array.Length]`. If n is in the range, of course.
This would be useful sometimes.

Comment: Because that's not what a `Queue` was created for.

Comment: I guess it could be useful sometimes to read the n'th element. If you could write to it, though, it would simply be an array or list. However, you are relying on an implementation detail. Not all queues in all languages are implemented as arrays. Random access is not part of the philosophy  of a queue. In other words: if it had random access, it wouldn't be a queue.

Comment: It was requested and declined: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4961

Comment: queue follows First-in-First-Out principle, so you can't access a element at 'n' unless before n-1 elements dequeued, queues are for special purposes. Use simple arrays.

Comment: @lokesh1729 Simple arrays have worse performance if you want to remove items at the front. So I might write my own queue data structure with random access instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the nth element using `ElementAt`:

```
var element = q.ElementAt(index);
```

Since that's an `IEnumerable` extension method, you have to add `using System.Linq;`

However, you can't write the nth element since that's not what the Queue was made for. That would just break the most important feature of a Queue which is First-In/First-Out. If you can insert an item at some index, there is no point in using a Queue in the first place.

Comment: I wasn't talking about inserting items. But really, the option to insert items would defeat the point of using a queue in the first place? I admit that part of the point of a queue is that the order of the items is preserved. But another part is that you can add and remove items at opposite ends of the data structure in constant time.

Comment: @NounVerber That is not a queue. You either need to create your own Data Structure. Or use one of the flexiable available ones like a List. What does *write the nth element* mean ?

Comment: What does write the nth element mean? I meant, in this case, replacing it with a different item. So if there was a 2 there, I can put a 5 there instead.

Comment: @NounVerber You can update the properties of an object at the nth element by retrieving it using `ElementAt`. But you can't replace it. That is not a Queue. I think you should not use a queue in your case.